# how to get datetime type column data into 'MM/YYYY' format using flask SqlAlchemy in python

Tags: python-3.x, flask-sqlalchemy

I have an column in the database which is datetime type and i have to retrieve date into 'MM/YYYY' format.

what i have to do this in sqlalchemy, python?

**my current query is as follow =>**

**session.query(Model.models.DefineStructureOfTable.Detail.AsOfDate).filter(
Model.models.DefineStructureOfTable.Detail.ID.in_(getId)).all()**

currently it gives me result as **datetime** type date

Please Help!

Answer (score 2):

If your question is how to convert `datetime` into the format `MM/YYYY`, you can use [strftime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime).

```
result.strftime("%m/%Y")
```

If your question is about how you make the database return a different format, you can't. You can't change the types of the underlying database. But you could change the type to `TEXT`, and just store the string directly - not recommended in this format because it will be hard to sort.

Alternatively add a method or property to the model to get the datetime in the right format.

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    month_and_year = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    
    @property
    def formatted_month_and_year(self):
        return self.month_and_year.strftime("%m/%Y")
```